# "Had decided to call" vs."had decided that we should call"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, past-perfect, clauses

I have a question regarding using "had decided". I'm not sure if I can use either an infinitive form of a verb or a modal verb:

> - We had decided to call each other when we are in danger.
> - We had decided that we should call each other when we are in danger.

I think I've heard people use both, not sure if I can use past perfect with an infinitive and *would/should/could*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with either of OP's constructions, and it's a bit pointless to speculate on possible nuances of meaning, but #1 is far more common overall. Perhaps that's partly because the infinitive form is more flexible. (counts from Google Books)...

> [He agreed to help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20agreed%20to%20help%22&oq=%22he%20agreed%20to%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...5329.8889.7.9431.15.15.0.0.0.0.65.677.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.lXRxJkLSXLk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (83,100)
>    [He agreed that he would help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20agreed%20that%20he%20would%20help%22&oq=%22he%20agreed%20that%20he%20would%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...4783.5599.6.6093.5.5.0.0.0.0.87.288.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.JAYqXvEOfGg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (5)
>    [He agreed he would help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20agreed%20he%20would%20help%22&oq=%22he%20agreed%20he%20would%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...8688.11824.5.12086.10.10.0.0.0.2.328.1080.7j1j1j1.10.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.UQ9Uwg5QI_Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (7)
>
> [He asked to help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20asked%20to%20help%22&oq=%22he%20asked%20to%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...210543.215340.8.215795.21.15.0.0.0.3.110.803.14j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.tlpE9AvifmA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (21,100)
>    [He asked if he could help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20asked%20if%20he%20could%20help%22&oq=%22he%20asked%20if%20he%20could%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...37219.40507.9.40759.13.13.0.0.0.0.94.705.13.13.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.wMDAHXWkUhY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (19,900)
>
> [He asked to be [whatever]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20asked%20to%20be%22&oq=%22he%20asked%20to%20be%22&gs_l=serp.3...10738.13233.17.13751.16.10.0.0.0.3.124.571.8j2.10.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.HRgmq79Gqcs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (1,180,000)
>    [He asked that he should be [whatever]](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20asked%20that%20he%20should%20be%22&oq=%22he%20asked%20that%20he%20should%20be%22&gs_l=serp.3...11568.13654.16.14165.3.3.0.0.0.0.59.130.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.ZFdyVPusUfM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (12,000)
>
> [He wanted to help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20wanted%20to%20help%22&oq=%22he%20wanted%20to%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...152586.158344.10.159439.26.20.0.0.0.4.136.1226.19j1.20.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.06pHZIfyFXk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (537,000)
>    [He refused to help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20refused%20to%20help%22&oq=%22he%20refused%20to%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...60146.63957.11.65165.15.15.0.0.0.1.80.887.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.RRgiNr1N1ro&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (52,400)
>    [He rushed to help](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22agreed%20to%20buy%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20rushed%20to%20help%22&oq=%22he%20rushed%20to%20help%22&gs_l=serp.3...257821.263587.18.264075.37.26.0.0.0.7.105.1601.25j1.26.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.gkKPKlsLuOY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=dd9628712b96acc6&biw=1680&bih=892) (4,320)

(There aren't really any equivalents to OP's "that-clause" for those last three).

---

The fact of OP having used past perfect is totally irrelevant. I could change all instances of simple past *he agreed* above to *he **had** agreed*, and it wouldn't affect any of the ratios (I'd just get lower numbers overall, because past perfect is less common).

---

EDIT: I should say past perfect isn't *totally* irrelevant. To me, at least, it raises serious problems regarding *"...when we **are** in danger"*. Personally, I'd let that pass if the main verb had been simple past *(We decided...)*, but with past perfect the temporal flexibility of English is being stretched to breaking point. I think it would have to be expressed as *"...**if** we **were** in danger"* to pass muster.

Comment: Wow, makes perfect sense! I'm learning so much, thanks to you!

Comment: @Pato: You might wish to note that *"I agree to help **when** you get into trouble"* implies I think you *probably* (or even *certainly*) ***will** get into trouble* at some point in the future. But there's no such expectation implied in *"I agree to help **if** you get into trouble"* (I might think it's highly likely, or highly *unlikely*, or I may not have an opinion; the word **if** itself implies nothing about this).